# golang exec background process and get its pid

Tags: go, exec, pid

**Situation:**

I want to run a command that puts itself into the background. If it makes it more possible, then I'll run the command in foreground and bring it into the background by myself.

**Question:**

When the process runs in background: *how can I get it's `pid` using Go?*

**I tried the following:**

```
cmd := exec.Command("ssh", "-i", keyFile, "-o", "ExitOnForwardFailure yes", "-fqnNTL", fmt.Sprintf("%d:127.0.0.1:%d", port, port), fmt.Sprintf("%s@%s", serverUser, serverIP))
cmd.Start()
pid := cmd.Process.Pid
cmd.Wait()
```

This returns instantly and leaves `ssh` running in the background. But it's `pid` is not the `pid` of the running `ssh` process. Moreover, it's the `pid` of the parent `ssh` process before it forked and backgrounded itself.

Comment: What do you mean by "background"? When you `Start()` your `Cmd` you already have a separate child process (with proper `Process.Pid`) running concurrently to your Go application. Maybe you just need to remove `-f` from ssh flags?

Comment: I need the process to continue running after my go process exits. I then need to be able to kill the backgrounded ssh process in the future, for which I'll need to have stored its pid.

Comment: Hmm, actually you're right, the process continues if I don't Wait for it and just exit.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You don't need anything special, just don't tell ssh to background itself and don't `Wait()` for it. Example:

```
$ cat script.sh
#!/bin/sh
sleep 1
echo "I'm the script with pid $$"
for i in 1 2 3; do
        sleep 1
        echo "Still running $$"
done
$ cat proc.go
package main

import (
       "log"
       "os"
       "os/exec"
)

func main() {
     cmd := exec.Command("./script.sh")
     cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
     err := cmd.Start()
     if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
     }
     log.Printf("Just ran subprocess %d, exiting\n", cmd.Process.Pid)
}
$ go run proc.go
2016/09/15 17:01:03 Just ran subprocess 3794, exiting
$ I'm the script with pid 3794
Still running 3794
Still running 3794
Still running 3794
```

Comment: Hello, your example is working correctly but the process becomes in `S` mode after it finish. Is there a better way to achieve same results ? Where i can get a pid in order to check if finished. In my case i don't need the output as there will be log file containing the results already if finished successfully

Comment: @Mostafa Hussein please what is S mode?

Answer (score 6):

@Mostafa Hussein, can use goroutine waiting, manage process

```
function main()
    cmd := exec.Command( "shell.sh" )
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    pid := cmd.Process.Pid
    // use goroutine waiting, manage process
    // this is important, otherwise the process becomes in S mode
    go func() { 
        err = cmd.Wait()
        fmt.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
    }()
    return nil
}
```

Comment: please what is S mode?

Comment: He means "interruptible sleep" as shown by `ps`. It's also called a zombie process. Basically, it's waiting for the parent process to get its exit code, and if you don't wait for it, it'll stick around forever.