# How to start an application using GO and move on afterwards

Tags: go

I have an App I am trying to write whose responsibility it is to read through a yaml file and execute tasks associated with it.

Below is an example of the yaml that starts the application, in this case its starting up a web server.

```
runProcess:
  - "sleep 5"
  - "go run server.go"
```

This is read by my Go application using viper which sends the commands to my function

```
func BuildRun() {

    log.Println("Running buildSteps")
    for _, step := range viper.GetStringSlice("buildSteps") {
        Run(step)
    }

    log.Println("Running runProcess")

    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() {
        Start("runProcess")
        wg.Done()
    }()
    wg.Wait()

    fmt.Println("Done")
```

```
func Start(step string) {

    for _, command := range viper.GetStringSlice(step) {

        log.Println("Command: ", command)
        arg := strings.Fields(command)
        cmd := exec.Command(arg[0], arg[1:]...)
        err := cmd.Start()

        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        log.Printf("Waiting for command to finish...")

        err = cmd.Wait()
        log.Printf("Command finished with error: %v", err)
    }
}
```

The problem is, is that it never gets to the `Done` message. This is the output of the application:

```
2022/07/01 12:52:07 Verifying devrun.yaml exists
2022/07/01 12:52:07 Starting Application
go version go1.18.3 darwin/arm64

2022/07/01 12:52:07 Running buildSteps

2022/07/01 12:52:09 Running runProcess
2022/07/01 12:52:09 Command:  sleep 5
2022/07/01 12:52:09 Waiting for command to finish...
2022/07/01 12:52:14 Command finished with error: <nil>
2022/07/01 12:52:14 Command:  go run server.go
2022/07/01 12:52:14 Waiting for command to finish...
```

And it just hangs there, which is understandable because the application is running and hasn't ended yet. I am stuck on how to get it past this though and validate that the application has started up.

My application does work if the web socket is in use

```
2022/07/01 12:58:31 Verifying devrun.yaml exists
2022/07/01 12:58:31 Starting Application
go version go1.18.3 darwin/arm64

2022/07/01 12:58:31 Running buildSteps

2022/07/01 12:58:33 Running runProcess
2022/07/01 12:58:33 Command:  sleep 5
2022/07/01 12:58:33 Waiting for command to finish...
2022/07/01 12:58:38 Command finished with error: <nil>
2022/07/01 12:58:38 Command:  go run server.go
2022/07/01 12:58:38 Waiting for command to finish...
2022/07/01 12:58:40 Command finished with error: exit status 1

Done
```

Comment: The call cmd.Wait() does not return until the command terminates.  Are you expecting `go run server.go` to terminate quickly or run for a long time?  If the latter, start a goroutine to wait on the process.

Comment: you can store the process id after the cmd.Start() and do not wait for cmd.Wait, once other task are done you can kill the process with process id https://stackoverflow.com/a/39513126/10984192

Comment: could you please provide more details on what are you trying to achieve? The same yaml file you shared only has one task but would there be more tasks in this yaml file and do you want to execute all of them even if one of them is a blocking script?

Comment: @CeriseLimón Yea, sorry. So the server.go file is a web server, I want it to be long running and just either listen for an exit code or just make sure the server is running so the script can listen for other events unrelated to this post (mostly SIG kill commands).  I will try what shubham said and not do the wait and try to handle something with the PID instead.